# My nav code in Bootstrap doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The code at the and of this message I use in WebStorm. Have you any idea what I am doing wrong? Maybe some CDN errors or incorrect in the code?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>DateLab</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
    
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DateLab</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul class="navbar navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hoe werkt het</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wie zijn wij</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Situation output now: 
[image]

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: What is your expectations ?

Comment: Something like this, responsive. Bootstrap works not good I think. See picture in the questio

Comment: what is the result that you want ? I don't get what you say !

Comment: See you now the two pictures in my message?

Comment: It's clear that you miss some css files.

Comment: Is the css file from https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css not enough? Are the scripts in the right places?

Comment: no the css file the you post is not enough! and the script are in the right place !!

Comment: Thanks! I used a wrong version of Bootstrap!

Answer (score 1):

I just changed you CDN links for sources. because you were using the Beta version of bootstrap. Also, there was some issue with HTML code I just replaced it.

check these useful links

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/

[https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/)

Just be careful when you use any library and framework. try to use the stable versions. Also always include scripts at end of the code. because your code was generating some js errors.

```html
   <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hoe werkt het</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Wie zijn wij</a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQ</a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```